# Microsoft Teams crashes when picking a file in task module window on IOS

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm working on a Bot for Teams Application.
My bot is able to work with attachments not only in direct conversations but in channels too. That was implemented with the Task Module in 4 steps:

1. User requests card with the button that opens task window.
2. The Task Module loads our web site with the file picker form.
3. User clicks on file picker button and choose a file.
4. User clicks on submit button and file starts to upload.

After latest Teams update the app started to crash when user is trying to pick the file on iOS devices (iOS 13.06).

We use input to pick the file and we support multiple file selection:

The iOS Teams App Version: 2.0.18, Build: 1.077.2020072902 (general)

it is strange that on some iOS devices the App still works well (for example iPad, iOS 12.4.8).
Unfortunately there are no tools to debug it on my side.
This seems to me like a bug because everything worked well on all platforms (Android, iOS, Desktop, Web) before the update.

Comment: iPad OS 13.6.1 is available. Have you given that a shot?

Comment: In case it is only crashing in iOS and working fine in android, try upgrading the iOS version as @JoeBeck suggested.

Comment: I've got IOS 13.6.1 on my iPhone 11 pro and just updated the Teams app to latest (1.077.2020081405 (general)) and it still crashes.

Comment: iPhone 11 Max pro, IOS version 13.7, teams app 2.0.24 build: 1.077.2020101604 (general) ... Still crashes

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the next update of the Teams app.